# Bucketing and counting for histogram in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to implement a histogram based on the data stored in MongoDB. I want to get counts based on bucketing. I have to create buckets based on only one input value that is number of groups. for example group = 4 
Consider there are multiple transactions are running and we stored transaction time as one of the fields. I want to calculate counts of transactions based on time required to finish the transaction.
How can I use aggregation framework or map reduce to create a bucketing?

```
Sample data:
{
   "transactions":    {
      "149823":       {
         "timerequired": 5
      },
      "168243":       {
         "timerequired": 4
      },
      "168244":       {
         "timerequired": 10
      },
      "168257":       {
        "timerequired": 15
      },
      "168258":       {
         "timerequired": 8
      },
      "timerequired": 18
      }
}
```

In the output I want to print bucket size and count of transactions fall into that bucket.

Bucket      count

0-5           2

5-10          2

10-15         1

15-20         1

Answer (score 5):

From mongo version 3.4, the functions [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) and [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) are available . They can easily solve your request:

```
db.transactions.aggregate( [
   {
     $bucketAuto: {
         groupBy: "$timerequired",
         buckets: 4
     }
   }
])
```